# unable to copy files from linux server to local machine

Tags: python, linux, copy

Below  is the code written to copy files from linux server to local PC , but i am facing "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: \XXXXX" error .
What is wrong in this , could anyone help with this ?
Thanks in advance !!

```
import os
import paramiko 
import time
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.load_system_host_keys() 
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('xxxx', port=22, username='yyy', password='zzz')
time.sleep(5)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
localpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
remotepath = '/xxx/yyy/zzz'
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Just asking the obvious question.   You've tried this manually and it works?  The remote linux server accepts password logins for ssh?

Comment: Could you elaborate on which line the error is?

Comment: Error is at this line : sftp.put(localpath, remotepath) and yes , i am able to copy manually

Comment: Did you check your local machine directory permissions for writing?

Comment: yes, i have changed the rights to everyone for that particular folder

Comment: There is a previous Stackoverflow questioning whether sftp.put can handle directories as targets. You may have to copy one file at a time.

Comment: Yes this is helpful , i used get instead of put . copy successful .